# Varying the return type of a templated member function of a class based off of a separate templated member

Tags: c++, templates

Pardon the poor phraseology in my title, I think my example will do much more to show what I'm trying to do, and the problem I'm facing:

Here is a class template that I am currently trying to create:

```
template<typename T>
class IID{
public:
    IID(T x){a = x;}
    template<typename X>
    vector</*/////*/> operator()(X& rng, unsigned int n){
        vector</*/////*/> returnval(n);
        generate(returnval.begin(),returnval.end(),bind(a,ref(rng)));
        return returnval;   
    };
private:
    T a;
};
```

The constructor takes an input from the C++ random library. These classes are templated in the following manner:

```
uniform_int_distribution<double> T;
```

Is there a way to get the "double" from the above statement in the following line of code?

```
vector</*/////*/> operator()(X& rng, unsigned int n){
```

I can solve the problem by doing the following, but it contains a redundancy I'd like to avoid:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
class IID{
public:
    IID(T x){a = x;}
    template<typename X>
    vector<F> operator()(X& rng, unsigned int n){
        vector<F> returnval(n);
        generate(returnval.begin(),returnval.end(),bind(a,ref(rng)));
        return returnval;   
    };
private:
    T a;
};
```

Because it means that instantiation of a member of the IID class is of the form:

```
 uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0,100);
 IID<uniform_real_distribution<double>, double > a(dist);
```

Which is littered with redundancies!

I'd much rather have:

```
 uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0,100);
 IID<uniform_real_distribution<double> > a(dist);
```

which looks much cleaner.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no requirement on the random number generator you are using to define the type, the easiest way is to actually just get the value of the expression you are executing:

```
template<typename T>
class IID{
public:
    // ...
    template<typename X>
    auto operator()(X& rng, unsigned int n)
        -> std::vector<decltype(std::bind(std::declval<T&>(), std::ref(rng))())> {
        std::vector<decltype(std::bind(std::declval<T&>(), std::ref(rng))())> rc;
        std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(rc), n, std::bind(this->a, std::ref(rng)));
        return rc;
    }

private:
    T a;
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I understand that decltype returns the type of something, and I understand that you're binding the () operator to the RNG. But what is / why do we use declval<T>()?

Comment: `std::declval<T>()` yields an object of type `T` similar to your `a`. I'm using it mainly because off-hand I don't know if I can use `this->a` in a late return. Inside the function it could be replaced by `this->a`. Since `a` is actually a non-`const` reference in this context, it should probably be corrected to be `std::decltype<T&>()` (I'll fix that). The function template is actually not defined because it is only ever used in non-evaluated contexts.

Comment: Ah, so declval<T> allows us to discern information about member functions of T without directly instantiating a T object, correct? Also, I'm a little confused on what you mean by "The function template is actually not defined because it is only ever used in non-evaluated contexts."

Comment: `std::declval<T>()` is a function returning whatever `T` is as a suitable reference: `template <typename T> typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept;` The basic idea is that yields something which can be used as if there were a way to create the object. However, the function is only declared and can, thus, only be used where it isn't executed at run-time, e.g., as arguments to `decltype()`, `noexcept()`, or `sizeof()` (I think this a complete list of non-evaluated contexts).

Comment: Ah, now I understand what that sentence meant. Thanks!